# Remove lost password form and URL

Tags: redirect, wp-login-form, password

I've shut down password resets for all users.

I now need to prevent `/wp-login.php?action=lostpassword` from doing anything should anyone manually input the URL into their browser.

i.e. I don't want the password reset form to show.

Can I disable the action that's being passed by the URL or can I redirect `/wp-login.php?action=lostpassword` to `/wp-login.php`?

Comment: wont a simple redirect do the trick?

Comment: @SagiveSEO I'm currently testing this plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/

Comment: i think that's the easiest solution... (and the fastest one)  ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hi Please try to use this in your functions.php it will redirect user to login form when user try to access lost password page:

```
add_action('init','possibly_redirect'); 
function possibly_redirect(){ 
   if (isset( $_GET['action'] )){  
     if ( in_array( $_GET['action'], array('lostpassword', 'retrievepassword') ) ) {
        wp_redirect( '/wp-login.php' ); exit;
     }
  }
}
```

Or Please follow below approach used from this answer  [answered here with some details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34905812/redirecting-a-url-with-an-action-parameter/34906203#34906203) based on comments of @Clarus Dignus

```
function disable_lost_password() {
    if (isset( $_GET['action'] )){
        if ( in_array( $_GET['action'], array('lostpassword', 'retrievepassword') ) ) {
            wp_redirect( wp_login_url(), 301 );
            exit;
        }
    }
}
add_action( "login_init", "disable_lost_password" );
```

Comment: This works. I've since discovered that the [retrievepassword action also needs to be conditionally checked for](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34906203/2971649).

Comment: updated answer based on you comment and discovered answer !!

Comment: Note that you're running this on init where the action GET paramter isn't always set, so we would see PHP notices in many places - `isset()` would come to the rescue ;-)

Comment: @birgire I vaguely understand. Am I to check if `lostpassword` and `retrievepassword` are `isset()` before calling them in the array? I've trued to produce the errors you're describing by targeting `http://example.com/wp-login.php?action=` (i.e. no value for action parameter) but errors aren't being printed to my page.

Comment: what I had in mind was an additional `isset( $_GET['action'] )` check, before we use it @ClarusDignus

Comment: @birgire Is this implementation correct?: http://pastebin.com/rYVkAQXN. Furthermore, should I be checking if I'm on the login page?. I came across [admin_init](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_init) and then discovered [login_init](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/login_init/). Should I be hooking into this instead?

Comment: yes that looks ok and it's usually better to narrow the scope as much as we can, so I would try hooks that are more specific than init. (ps: I'm signing off for the evening) @ClarusDignus

Answer (score 1):

You can use *.htaccess* and *mod_rewrite*.

Forbidden response:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^action=lostpassword$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^wp-login.php$ - [F,NC]
```

Redirect to wp-login.php:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^action=lostpassword$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^wp-login.php$ wp-login.php [R=301,NC,QSD,L]
```

(for QSD flag you need Apache 2.4.0+)

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an older thread, but I have a couple of improvements.  First, since they can use GET or POST, I would be checking for $_REQUEST instead of $_GET

Second, redirect them somewhere useless, instead of back to your site.  Like 'http://127.0.0.1'  If they don't have a web server there, the bot will at least stall for a few seconds waiting for a reply.  Anything we can do to hinder these a-holes.

Comment: not a coder myself but just found this needed solution, can you elaborate on using $_REQUEST instead of $_GET?  Does that mean I would just replace each instance of $_GET in the code above where it's shown in if(isset and if(in_array   ? Or does the code change other than the replacement?

Comment: $_REQUEST combines $_GET, $_POST and $_COOKIE.  Which takes precedence if two have the same keyed value, will depend on your php setup

Comment: Thank you @de-coder, that is very helpful but so that I fully understand, would I then use the code from above modified like so: 'function disable_lost_password() {
    if (isset( $_REQUEST['action'] )){
        if ( in_array( $_REQUEST['action'], array('lostpassword', 'retrievepassword') ) ) {
            wp_redirect( wp_login_url(), 301 );
            exit;
        }
    }
}
add_action( "login_init", "disable_lost_password" );'

Comment: You are using $_REQUEST correctly there.  Just use it instead of $_GET and it watches for $_GET and $_POST at the same time, saving a little code.

Comment: thank you very much! I'm so grateful that you and others are generous with your time and experience. :-)